# Greek letters not showing in Integral bounds

Tags: greek, letters, integral

I am trying to write the definition of the Fourier Series in MikTex. However, on the Integral bounds the Greek letters to not show up.

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\begin{definition}{}
\label{FourierSeriesDef}

The Fourier series of a function $f(x)$ is given by

\begin{equation} \label{eq:FourierSeries}
 f(x) = \frac{1}{2}a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_ncos(nx) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_nsin(nx),
\end{equation}

where

$$
a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx 
$$

\end{definition}
```

and the output is

[image: Output of above]

Comment: Cannot reproduce ([minimal code](https://hastebin.com/uqunifadob.tex), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnYYw.png))

Comment: Ah yes. I have done the same as you. I checked my latex class file and I noticed that I changed the math font to "EB Garamond". Changing it back to default or something like "Arno Pro" solved the issue. 

Do you know why this happens with EB Garamond. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Still cannot reproduce ([minimal code](https://hastebin.com/jefokeqide.tex), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Q0P.png)).  It's impossible to say without minimal code from your side.

Comment: Welcome! If you are using `unicode-math`, then you cannot properly set the maths font to EB Garamond as it isn't one. However, I'd expect more spectacular failures in that case. If you are using `ebgaramond-maths`, please scrutinise the console output and/or log file, and read the manual. This package only supports limited maths and ought not be used in documents requiring full mathematical support. (However, the console/log does tell you how to work around the limitations, if you really insist. I wouldn't recommend that, but it is your document and not mine, after all.)

Comment: However, looking at @HenriMenke's code, I guess `ebgaramond-maths` isn't involved, if that example doesn't demonstrate the problem. (And I don't think pi would be affected anyway, for independently reasons.)

Comment: Please do tell us which font packages you load. Please also tell us which TeX engine you use to compile your document -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using `unicode-math`, the following setup works fine for me with the latest version of EB Garamond downloaded from https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads/

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=up,Numbers=Lining]{EBGaramond12-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont[range=it]{EBGaramond12-Italic.otf}
\setmathfont[range={}]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

\[
a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. It might be a good idea to add the option `Scale=MatchLowercase` to the second and third `\setmathfont` instructions.

Comment: @Mico Trying to use a text font for maths will look like garbage anyway, so it doesn't really matter.  But thanks for the suggestion.